# How to ignore sync if value is null in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a form where I will sync my attributes (it's like tags) but the issue is I get error while select or even not select any attribute.

Here is the error I get:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for
>   column 'attribute_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `product_attributes`
>   (`attribute_id`, `product_id`) values (*parameters, 65))

Before codes I need to explain what I try to do:

1. Select my attributes while creating new post
2. Give value to selected attribute
3. save `product_id` `arribute_id` and `attribute_value` in `product_attributes` table.

Here is my blade:

```js
$(function() {
        $('a.pl').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#phone').append('<div class="col-md-6"><select class="tagsselector mb-20 form-control" name="attribute[]"><option value="{{ $attribute->id }}">{{ $attribute->title }}</option></select></div><div class="col-md-6"><input name="attribute_value" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Value"></div>');
        });
        $('a.mi').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#phone input').length > 1) {
                $('#phone').children().last().remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="RegSpLeft" id="phone" style="margin-top:30px;">
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                             <label for="attributes" hidden>Attributes</label>
                             <select class="mb-20 form-control" name="attributes[]">
                               <option value="" selected>Select Attributes</option>
                               @foreach($attributes as $attribute)
                                   <option value="{{ $attribute->id }}">{{ $attribute->title }}</option>
                               @endforeach
                             </select>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                             <label for="attribute_value" hidden>attribute value</label>
                             <input name="attribute_value" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Value">
                           </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="RegSpRight">
                             <a href="#" class="pl">+</a>
                             <a href="#" class="mi">-</a>
                         </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function create()
    {
      $categories = Category::all();
      $subcategories = Subcategory::all();
      $attributes = Attribute::all();
      if (is_null($attributes)) {
        $attributes = [];
      }
      $user = Auth::user();
      return view('admin.products.create', compact('user', 'categories', 'subcategories', 'attributes'));
    }
```

My `Product` model:

```
public function attributes()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes', 'product_id', 'attribute_id');
  }
```

My `Attribute` model:

```
public function products(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
```

Comment: hi bro you there ?

Comment: leave a chat discussion link here

Comment: @Demonyowh hi bro, yes i'm here but our discussion has been frozen. I'm afraid we have to chat till new discussion open for us.

Comment: ok now what's your prob here ? it seems that the value is not an integer ..

Comment: exactly, this is my db structure `$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->integer('attribute_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('attribute_id')->references('id')->on('attributes');
            $table->string('attribute_value')->nullable();`

Comment: as you see my attribute_value is not integer and it suppose to get value of admin input's eg. `product_id = 5` `attribut = CPU` `attribute_value = Core i7`

Comment: ok i think you're passing a value that is not an integer that's what i mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156903/discussion-between-mafortis-and-demonyowh).