# Return values to null in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm working on e-commerce project with Laravel 5.5 where in my products table I have 2 columns named `discount` and `discount_date`, what I want is when the date of column `discount_date` comes both `discount` and `discount_date` columns become null automatically.

How can I do that?

Update:

productcontroller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Subcategory;
use App\Category;
use App\Attribute;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use DB;
use Storage;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
use jpmurray\LaravelCountdown\Countdown;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin']);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('admin.products.index', compact('products'));
    }

    public function show($slug)
    {
        $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        $countdown = DB::table('products')->where('discount_date', '!=', null)->pluck('discount_date');
        $now = Carbon::now();
        return view('admin.products.show', compact('product', 'countdown', 'now'));
    }



    public function create()
    {
      $categories = Category::all();
      $subcategories = Subcategory::all();
      $attributes = Attribute::all();
      $user = Auth::user();
      return view('admin.products.create', compact('user', 'categories', 'subcategories', 'attributes'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'title'=>'required|max:225',
          'slug' =>'required|max:255|unique:products',
          'user_id' =>'required|numeric',
          'image_one' =>'nullable|image',
          'image_two' =>'nullable|image',
          'image_three' =>'nullable|image',
          'image_four' =>'nullable|image',
          'short_description' => 'nullable|max:1000',
          'description' => 'required|max:100000',
          'subcategory_id' => 'required|numeric',
          'discount' => 'nullable|numeric',
          'discount_date' => 'nullable|date',
          'price' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

      $product = new Product;

      $product->title = $request->input('title');
      $product->slug = $request->input('slug');
      $product->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
      $product->description = $request->input('description');
      $product->short_description = $request->input('short_description');
      $product->subcategory_id = $request->input('subcategory_id');
      $product->discount = $request->input('discount');
      $product->discount_date = $request->input('discount_date');
      $product->price = $request->input('price');



      if ($request->hasFile('image_one')) {
        $image = $request->file('image_one');
        $filename = 'product' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('image_one')->move($location, $filename);

        $product->image = $filename;
      }


      $product->save();

      $product->attributes()->sync($request->attributes, false);


      //Display a successful message upon save
      Session::flash('flash_message', 'Product, '. $product->title.' created');
      return redirect()->route('admin.products.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
      $product = Product::find($id);
      $categories = Category::all();
      $users = User::all();
      $subcategories = Subcategory::all();
      $attributes = Attribute::all();
      $attributes2 = array();
      foreach($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributes2[$attribute->id] = $attribute->title;
      }
      return view('admin.products.edit', compact('product', 'categories', 'users', 'subcategories', 'attributes2'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

      $product = Product::find($id);
      if ($request->input('slug') == $product->slug) {
             $this->validate($request, array(
               'title'=>'required|max:225',
               'description' =>'required|min:4|max:100000',
               'short_description' =>'nullable|min:4|max:1000',
               'image_one' =>'sometimes|image',
               'image_two' =>'sometimes|image',
               'image_three' =>'sometimes|image',
               'image_four' =>'sometimes|image',
               'discount' =>'nullable|numeric',
               'discount_date' =>'nullable|date',
               'user_id' =>'required|numeric',
               'price' =>'required|numeric',
               'subcategory_id' => 'sometimes|integer',
             ));
         } else {
         // validate the date
         $this->validate($request, array(
           'slug' =>'required|max:225|unique:products',
           'title'=>'required|max:225',
           'description' =>'required|min:4|max:100000',
           'short_description' =>'nullable|min:4|max:1000',
           'image_one' =>'sometimes|image',
           'image_two' =>'sometimes|image',
           'image_three' =>'sometimes|image',
           'image_four' =>'sometimes|image',
           'discount' =>'nullable|numeric',
           'discount_date' =>'nullable|date',
           'user_id' =>'required|numeric',
           'price' =>'required|numeric',
           'subcategory_id' => 'sometimes|integer',
             ));
         }

      $product = Product::where('id',$id)->first();

      $product->title = $request->input('title');
      $product->description = $request->input('description');
      $product->slug = $request->input('slug');
      $product->user_id = $request->input('user_id');
      $product->short_description = $request->input('short_description');
      $product->image_one = $request->input('image_one');
      $product->image_two = $request->input('image_two');
      $product->image_three = $request->input('image_three');
      $product->image_four = $request->input('image_four');
      $product->discount = $request->input('discount');
      $product->discount_date = $request->input('discount_date');
      $product->price = $request->input('price');
      $product->subcategory_id = $request->input('subcategory_id');

      if ($request->hasFile('image_one')) {
        $image = $request->file('image_one');
        $filename = 'product' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/');
        $request->file('image_one')->move($location, $filename);

        $oldFilename = $product->image_one;
        $product->image_one = $filename;
        Storage::delete($oldFilename);
      }

      $product->save();
      $product->attributes()->sync($request->attributes);

      return redirect()->route('products.index',
          $product->id)->with('flash_message',
          'Product, '. $product->title.' updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      $product->attributes()->detach();
      Storage::delete($product->image);
      $product->delete();

      return redirect()->route('products.index')
          ->with('flash_message',
           'Product successfully deleted');
    }
}
```

Update 2 `Product model`

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

  protected $table = 'products';

  protected $fillable = [
      'title', 'slug', 'image_one', 'image_two', 'image_three', 'image_four', 'short_description', 'description', 'price', 'discount', 'discount_date',
  ];

  public function category(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
  public function subcategory(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class);
  }

  public function attributes()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'product_attributes', 'product_id', 'attribute_id');
  }

  public function order(){
     return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
  }

  public function discounts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Discount::class, 'product_id', 'id');
  }


}
```

Update 3 base on `Bagus Tesa` answer:

Now i have discount table and everything is set, here is my `discountcontroller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Discount;
use App\Product;

class DiscountController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'isAdmin']);
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $discounts = Discount::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('admin.discounts.index', compact('discounts', 'products'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      //Validating title and body field
      $this->validate($request, array(
          'amount'=>'required|max:225',
          'valid_from' =>'required|date',
          'valid_to' =>'required|date',
          'product_id' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

      $discount = new Discount;

      $discount->amount = $request->input('amount');
      $discount->valid_from = $request->input('valid_from');
      $discount->valid_to = $request->input('valid_to');
      $discount->product_id = $request->input('product_id');


      $discount->save();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This is my `discount model`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Discount extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'discounts';

    protected $fillable = ['valid_from', 'valid_to', 'amount', 'product_id',];

    public function products(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
   }

   public function scopeValid($query){
         return $query->whereDate('valid_from', '>=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
                      ->whereDate('valid_to', '<=', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
   }
}
```

**Update 4:**

Now everything works except ending discount time which was my issue before all these changes.

[image: issue image]

As you can see in screenshot expire time still not comes but status of discount is expire.

Here is the code i use in my blade:

```
@if ($product->$discounts > $mytime)
 OK!
@else
 Expired!
@endif
```

And this is in my controller:

```
$count = $product->discounts()->valid()->get();
$discounts = Discount::where('product_id', '=', $product->id)->get();
$mytime = Carbon::now();
```

Comment: I suggest to extract discount and discount_date into their own table discounts (valid_from, valid_to, product_id, amount) and then just lookup the date along with the product id.

Comment: @Gordon you lost me half way, would you explain more?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to extract `discount` and `discount_date` into their own table, like

```
discounts (
    datetime valid_from, 
    datetime valid_to, 
    int product_id, 
    decimal amount
)
```

and then just lookup the discounts valid for a given date and product, e.g.

```
SELECT product_id, amount 
FROM discounts 
WHERE product_id = 42
AND (NOW() BETWEEN valid_from AND valid_to);
```

While this then requires an additional query or a join to fetch discounts, it is easier to maintain discounts in their own table. You don't need to remove expired discounts because the BETWEEN query makes sure you only get the discounts valid for the current time.

Also, this way you can keep the history of discounts. Something you'd lose when null'ing the columns. Even if you wanted to delete them, it would be easier because you can just delete all discounts where `NOW() > valid_to`.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do this with Laravel/Eloquent. But this is much more about database modeling than it is about a specific framework. Your framework should just allow this. I am sure it does somehow. But I don't know how.

*Note: I typed the code snippets from my head. You want to [doublecheck their syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+select+rows+between+a+date+range+%5Bmysql%5D)*

Comment: ok, here is a question, how do i save this data in `discounts` table while i create my product? because `datetime valid_from` `datetime valid_to` and `decimal amount` are not integer but they are input and i can't use like say `$product->discounts()->sync($request->discounts, false);`

Comment: @mafortis since you tagged this Laravel, I assume you are also using Eloquent. Unfortunately, I have no clue about Eloquent because I don't believe in ActiveRecord based ORMs. My naive guess is you will need to set up a relation of some sort and map the fields somehow. Sorry, if that's not helpful.

Comment: No bro that's fine. thanks for the idea. I will use eloquent if i want to use your solution but seems to me it's half way only.

Comment: Not really. When you use a separate table, you can have many discounts for a product and you can create the product without an initial discount. And even if you wanted to create a product initially with a discount, you could still do it in two queries in a transaction.

Comment: ok see, now i have my columns in my create blade and they are nullable , if i use your way i cant save my data why? because currently i have the exact same problem with my attributes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781412/how-to-ignore-sync-if-value-is-null-in-laravel   I can save `int` id but i cant save inputs just as date and price will be input in your solution. _so kind of know the feature of your solution unless you have an idea for it?_

Comment: @mafortis your framework should allow for a way to map object properties to column types. If it doesn't allow this consider using a framework that doesn't get in the way of creating a maintainable solution. I would assume Laravel/Eloquent allows this somehow, but IDK. I don't use them.

Comment: Laravel does allow to use map, but i don't have experience with that!  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#introduction

Comment: perhaps you will need to elaborate *i cant save inputs just as date and price will be input in your solution* more in another question. i think @Gordon's idea is good enough to go despite lacking eloquent chants - but hey, you can also use `DB::raw` for things right? also, please keep in mind that [`Collection`s operations will be done in memory](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php), performance wise.

Comment: @BagusTesa so what are you suggesting actually? that I use Gordon solution, and what is your suggestion for saving inputs? sorry but i didn't get it.

Comment: hi @mafortis, sorry for the hassle, could you share your `Product` model? for reference before jumping into example bandwagon. since this thing, i assume that each product had their own discount is not it? ps. i will try my best to provide you easy to understand example, once i got home.

Comment: @BagusTesa Hi bro, sorry for late respond I included my products model please take a look and if you can open new answer so we don't bother Gordon. thanks

Answer (score 2):

## **Original Question**:

> I'm working on e-commerce project with Laravel 5.5 where in my products table I have 2 columns named discount and discount_date, what I want is when the date of column discount_date comes both discount and discount_date columns become null automatically.

## Answer:

There is several way to tackle this:

- One, stick on this abominable approach and use [Laravel Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling) to set null the columns.
- The second idea is [Gordon's normalized table approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46804445/4648586).
- Third is using [MySQL Event Scheduler as suggested by Leonhard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46805211/4648586) to set null the columns.
- Add a couple line of code that **checks** and **nulls the discount's column** whenever you fetch the `Products`.

I will go with expanding Gordon's approach into Laravel's way because it features the ability to retain older discounts.

Gordon explained to have a table that looks like the following below.

```
discounts (
    int id,
    datetime valid_from, 
    datetime valid_to, 
    int product_id, 
    decimal amount,
    datetime created_at,
    datetime updated_at
)
```

*Note: the table structure is slightly changed to follow Laravel's convention (the `created_at` and `updated_at`; also added the primary key for clarity.*

To create such table, you could fire query by yourself or use [Laravel's Migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations). I will not cover the database creation as it is pretty unclear whether you used MySQL/MariaDB directly or helped PhpMyAdmin or perhaps you utilize Laravel migrations yourself. Assumed you have the table ready, named `discounts`, we will have to add a new model into Laravel:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Discount extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'discounts';
  protected $dates = ['valid_from', 'valid_to'];

  public function products(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
  }

  public function scopeValid($query){
        return $query->where('valid_from', '>=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
                     ->where('valid_to', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
  }
}
```

And you will need to add your `Product` model with the following relationship:

```
public function discounts(){
    return $this->hasMany(Discount::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Notice the `scopeValid($query)`, its our shortcut to do filtering on valid discounts - you can check [Laravel Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#local-scopes) on the documentation. The `->whereDate` is a specific [function to query datetime field](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereDate) in Laravel and you can find some example in [Laravel Diary](http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/). This way, you could filter the `Product`'s discount using the following eloquent query to get the discounts:

```
Product::find(1)->discounts()->valid()->get();
```

## The pro of this approach are:

- You can track the history of discounts
- Easier to maintain, less 'Task Scheduler' trouble.
- Readable for programmers.

## The cons of this approach are:

- You might tumble if there are two active discounts. But i don't think we can use [datetime for primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5022596/4648586).. and what if they overlap in sense that one spans from 10 Oct to 15 Oct and the other spans 11 Oct to 14 Oct? Funny is not it. Perhaps DBAs out there can suggest less-code trouble approach? This issue can be countered by checking the discount table every time a new discount is about to be added inside a [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions).

## Your next question:

> OK! even more confusing now :))), I included my controller in question please now see what fields that i have and where should i put the code. appreciate it.

## Next answer:

We don't know where this discounts going to be used.. I presume it will be shown in your `show($slug)` view (`admin.products.show`) or when calculating the total price.. something like that(?) We are programmers (and DBA, i suppose), not magicians..

**EDIT:**
Silly me for forgetting that `Carbon::today()` only gives you the date for today and `toDateString()` will give you only the date part. Hence the time reference should be `Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()`.

**EDIT:**
Wrong query, should be `where` to filter based on the date and time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. now I've already made `discounts` table and all models are set. i also created one discount and now how to show it in my product page?  PS: no one here try to do magic, all my codes are provided and we are talking base on my codes and not wishes. * I will update my question now.

Comment: hi again, i did show values in my product show blade with `@foreach($product->discounts as $tag)
                 <li>{{ $tag->valid_from->format('d-m-Y') }}</li>
                 <li>{{ $tag->valid_to->format('d-m-Y') }}</li>
                 <li>{{ number_format($tag->amount, 0) }}</li>
               @endforeach`  but there is issue, when the time comes discount is still valid!

Comment: `->whereDate('valid_to', '<=', Carbon::today()->toDateString())`, should i amend this one? it says that even if it `valid_to` today its still active -- yes the `<=` one.

Comment: `should i amend this one?`  yes you should if you really want to help! please see my update 4. jangan marah2 :)

Comment: good :), still is the same says `expired!` while still have 19min to `valid_to` time.

Comment: sorry, it was due to using `->toDateString()` instead of `->toDateTimeString()`. thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157042/discussion-between-bagus-tesa-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to set the values to null you can use the [MySQL Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html)

But I think it's an easier way to modify your select Statement to something like this:

```
select 
    id,
    IF(discount_date > now(), discount,null) as discount,
    IF(discount_date > now(), discount_date,null) as discount_date 
from product
```

You can test this on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/VCO21108)

In laravel it should be something like:

```
 $products = Product::orderby('id', 'desc')->select('all','your','columns', 'IF(discount_date > now(), discount,null) as discount', 'IF(discount_date > now(), discount_date,null) as discount_date')->get();
```

and

```
$countdown = DB::table('products')->where('discount_date', '>', 'now()')->pluck('discount_date');
```

Comment: well i have no idea how to use your code in my application! any help?

Comment: You can modify the laravel select with: $product = DB::table('product')->select('name', 'IF(discount_date > now(), discount,null) as discount','IF(discount_date > now(), discount_date,null) as discount_date')->get();

Comment: in which function i put these code? index,store,update...?

Comment: Sorry - i don't know your application. But there must be some PHP code where you access the content of the product table. Like "$product = DB::table('product')->get();" Do you have access to the sourcecode?

Comment: yes my index function is like that `public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::orderby('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('admin.products.index', compact('products'));
    }`

Comment: are you there??

Comment: OK! even more confusing now :))), I included my controller in question please now see what fields that i have and where should i put the code.  appreciate it.